# How to remove a child based on its value in Firebase using Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So i'm trying to make an app and I was testing spinners with firebase databases and I'm stuck on trying to find the node based on an editText in my database (in this case My Building) and find it's child (in this case buildingName) and deleting it's value. Unless I am reading the remove value wrong I think that it has to have a value to delete it so that is why I'm trying to delete buildingName instead of My Building(unless there is a way to do so:

Here is the code that is giving me some trouble:

```
fDatabaseRoot.child("buildings").child(AddBuilding.getText().toString().trim()).child("buildingName").removeValue();
```

Here is the database I'm referencing:

[image: Firebase Spinner Database]

I also have tried looking at other stack posts but none seem to answer my question.

Comment: It's not clear to me what problem you're running into.  You can delete any node you want, and everything under it will be gone if you have write permission on it.

Comment: I have write permissions. My problem is that it just isn't removing any child or value that I give it.

Comment: Check that you're building the correct path.  I see that you're using some class called AddBuilding.  It's entirely unclear to me if that's doing what you expect.  Also check the logs to make sure there wasn't actually an error.

Comment: The AddBuilding class is just my editText, what I expect it to do is what ever I type in the editText it should go to that node and find its child buildingName (which all of the nodes should definitely have and remove that value removing the editText node completely.

Comment: Perhaps that isn't working the way you expect.  Since you're not showing the code, it's impossible for us to tell.  Why don't you hard code the expected value in order to see if the delete works the way you expect.  If it does, then you'll know that the problem is in AddBuilder, and not with anything related to Firebase.

Comment: Ok I found it, my blind self didn't see that I was performing the wrong action I have the action that if building is filled and the room is empty do my code but i had the code in a different one saying that if both building and room are filled then delete it. I'm so sorry, I should have looked at it more

Comment: Good to hear that you found the problem. These types of issues are often easier to find of you recreate the problem in isolation, which (not entirely accidentally) is also the best way to get help with code-related problems here. See [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more on this.